# Filtering data from an API though an input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I currently have a dropdown menu as well as a search bar to search through data, but I'm having a few issues.

The API looks something like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Rodrick",
"last_name": "Costar",
"birthdate": "1944-05-06T04:22:45Z",
},
```

I currently have this to set my states

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const [searchNameFilter, setSearchNameFilter] = useState(data)
```

The function I'm using to search the name through the input is

const searchNames = event => {

```
let name = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
let result = []

console.log(name)

result = data.filter((d) => {
    return d.first_name.search(name)
})
setSearchNameFilter(result)
```

}

For the return function of the input, I have:

```
    <input name="name" type="text" onChange={(event) => searchNames(event)} />
    <main className="container">
        {data.map(user => {
            return (
                <div className="row">
                    <div>{user.first_name}{user.last_name}</div>
                    <div>{user.birthdate}</div>
```

The function works, but it's not filtering what I need. When I console log, it shows the characters I'm inputting, but it doesn't seem to be filtering anything. I also want it to filter it so it can search first or last name, but I have it set on first name to test it.

Answer (score 0):

For your `.search()` use case it doesn't work because it expects a regular expression ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)). Try using the `.includes()` method ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes))

Something like:

`<input name="name" type="text" onChange={searchNames} />`

```
function searchNames(ev) {
  const searchString = ev.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const result = data.filter(({ first_name }) => first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString));
  setSearchNameFilter(result);
}
```

Comment: Hm, I tried your solution, but it's not filtering out the results and when I console log the results, it's giving random results.

Comment: in my comparison I added, both strings must be in lower case, I fixed the example. Look my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-gagarin-b4o8b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah, I got it to work. Thanks. Just one more question, if I want to search by either first name or last name, would I have to make a new result variable?

Comment: I think the result might be the same, but in the comparison concatenate the two strings

Answer (score -1):

You need a state for your input box it’s react not vanilla JS and don’t use filter instead use find() function.

const [input, setInput] = useState(“”);

const found = data.find(element => element.first_name === input );

You need to set the ::found:: to sate to display it